# Easily switch network proxy on and off in Ubuntu 17.04

Tags: networking, unity, proxy, 17.04

I use Ubuntu 17.04 in a VM on a Windows notebook that sometimes is connected to a network which requires to use a proxy (manual configuration, no automatic detection supported) to access the Internet and sometimes is connected directly.

How can I most easily configure my Ubuntu to enable or disable the usage of said proxy and switch between them manually whenever I connect to a different network?

What I found on Ask Ubuntu so far only describes methods to edit e.g. `/etc/environment` to permanently configure a proxy, or to use system settings of some old or different desktop environments other than 17.04's Unity.

Answer (score 0):

You can create alias for this.

First at all, i'm using **.bashrc**:

```
export {http,https,ftp}_proxy="http://user:pass@domain:port"
export no_proxy="site.com"
```

If you already have set your proxy you can do this in your **.bash_aliases**:

```
export proxyEnv="export {http,https,ftp}_proxy"
alias updateEnv=". .bashrc"
alias unsetProxy="unset http_proxy && unset https_proxy && unset ftp_proxy"
alias proxyOn="sudo sed -i -e 's/#$proxyEnv/$proxyEnv/g' .bashrc && updateEnv"
alias proxyOff="sudo sed -i -e 's/$proxyEnv/#$proxyEnv/g' .bashrc && updateEnv && unsetProxy"
```

now update your alias:

```
source .bash_aliases
```

and you can use **proxyOff** and **proxyOn** for enable or disable.